# jGrowl sticky not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jgrowl

I'm using the jGrowl jQuery status-message plugin to display a sticky message on page load, and it works perfectly on all browsers except Internet Explorer 8. In this browser, there remains a small block, about 2 lines high but with no text, even after closing the sticky message. It does not have a close button, or anything, for that matter. Here is my code, which is placed in the document.onload function for IE:

```
$.jGrowl("Hi! Welcome to the site!", { sticky: true });
```

All other jGrowl settings are set to default, which is a floating message at the top right of the page.

Has anyone encountered this problem before, and perhaps know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in jGrowl, perhaps as a result of incompatibility with later releases of jQuery (the last update was in March 2008).

Maybe you can try [NMS Message](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/message?page=2)?

Comment: Hmm, I've long since moved on from that problem (never solved it though, just left jGrowl). But thanks for the reply - since no-one else replied, I'll give you the rep.